# How the default stl allocator allocates?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, allocator

I have my objects use overloaded new/delete operators as I use memory pools to allocate their memory.
They looks something like this:

```
class Foo{

 public:  
    void* operator new(size_t nbytes){

        return MemoryManager::GetInstance().AllocFooTypeMemory();

    }
    void operator delete(void* p)
    {
        MemoryManager::GetInstance().FreeFooTypeMemory(p);
    }

};
```

Now,my question is how it then works when I create an STL container of Foo pointers?[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/allocate/) it is written that the default STL allocator uses *::operator new* to allocate memory in the container.When does it use it?I tried to see if Foo's new gets triggered when calling

```
std::vector<Foo*> fooVector;
fooVector.reserve(10);
```

but nothing happens.

I have several questions:

Am I right to imply that in this case the allocator allocates only memory for pointers?

Does it mean the allocator calls "new" on Foo when the container holds objects and not pointers?

Also if yes,does it mean then I don't need to write custom allocator with mem pool if I already use a pool to allocate memory in the objects(like in Foo example)?

UPDATE:

To make it clear,I take into account that only the object which overload new/delete with memory pool are related to this question.I am completely aware that the object which do not have new/deleted overload still use default heap as a source for dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Nope, you're still using the default allocator with your code

Comment: I know that I still use the default allocator but will it use Foo's "new" to allocate?

Comment: It won't use `Foo` if you never tell it to use `Foo`.

Comment: `Foo` and `Foo*` are different things.

Comment: @T.C. I had no doubt they are ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default allocator can't use a class specific `operator new`,
because it doesn't contain a `new` expression; it calls the
`::operator new` function directly, separating allocation and
initialization.

In your case, of course, you don't have a container of `Foo`,
but of `Foo*`, so anything you define in `Foo` is irrelevant
(and you can't define an `operator new` for a pointer).

With regards to your specific questions:

- In an `std::vector<Foo*>`, the vector will only allocate
  pointers.  How could it do anything else?
- If the container contains `Foo`, rather than `Foo*`, the issue
  is more complicated; the default allocator will use `::operator new`
  to allocate the memory, and `::new (size_t, void*)...` to
  construct the object.
- You don't want to use a memory pool for objects in
  a container.  If the container is `std::vector`, the objects
  will be in contiguous memory, which generally shouldn't be taken
  from the pool, and for other types of containers, what is
  allocated is often not a `Foo` at all, but some more complex
  type which contains a `Foo`.

Comment: So it means I have to supply custom allocator to change the default   ::operator new to Foo's overloaded one?Is that what you say?

Comment: @MichaelIV: Yes, except the point that you are constructing a container of pointers, so the allocator is not used for allocating `Foo` objects at all, rendering the point moot!

Comment: Great!That's exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: @James Regarding your last point "You don't want to use a memory pool for objects in a container.", why not? Generally speaking, why would a memory pool even care? If I have a memory pool that I can ask to give me a pointer to a block of memory of length xyz bytes (optionally with alignment abc), what exactly speaks against using that memory pool with std::vector?

Comment: @antred The usual reason for using a memory pool is to use efficient fixed size allocators.  These won't work in any of the standard containers.

Comment: Wouldn't fixed-size allocators work well for all node-based containers as well as `std::deque<T>`? The tricky one is `std::vector<Foo, MyAlloc>` as that needs to deal with `.reserve(1<<25)`

Comment: @MSalters It depends on how the allocator is written; I _have_ used a pool allocator with `std::map`.  But it's tricky, because the allocations will not be for a `T`, but for a somewhat larger `__Node<T>`; you need some clever use of templates to avoid ending up with several pools.

Comment: @James Kanze I still don't quite understand. Surely fixed-size allocators aren't the only type of allocator with potential efficiency benefits. In cases where you have a lot of relatively small objects constantly getting created and destroyed, even a non-fixed-size allocator that forwards allocation/deallocation requests to a precreated memory pool might beat the default allocator, no? My understanding is that free store allocations are relatively expensive (since the free store is a system global resource).

Comment: @James Kanze "But it's tricky, because the allocations will not be for a T, but for a somewhat larger __Node<T>; you need some clever use of templates to avoid ending up with several pools."

Why not just make your allocator objects hold nothing more than a pointer to the underlying memory pool to use?

Comment: @antred I think your understanding is wrong.  All of the implementations of `malloc` I've seen get a large block of memory from the OS, and allocate from it, at least for small and medium sized blocks.  The global allocator should be no slower than your pool allocator if the pool allocator handles variable length blocks; in many cases, it will probably be faster.

Comment: @antred You've still got to allocate from the pool.  Either you support variable length allocation (in which case, you probably can't implement anything better than `malloc`), or you need some trickery to ensure the correct single size.

Comment: @James Kanze Any thread-safe malloc implementation will have to use some kind of synchronization. That could easily be more expensive than giving each thread its own memory pool allocator that can just take allocations from a pre-allocated chunk of memory without having to worry about other threads messing with that chunk. I imagine it might also improve locality of reference if each thread were to only operate on objects allocated from its own local chunk of memory.

Comment: @antred That's exactly what some implementations of `malloc` do.  If the `free` is in the same thread, there's no locking what so ever.  If the `free` is in a different thread, there is a queue of blocks to be freed which does require synchronization; `malloc` will come here and actually free these blocks only when it needs to.  Most allocations are without synchronization, and if the free is in the same thread, it is also without synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Overaloading new and delete operator, in your case, applies to Foo class only. That means, following calls use your custom new and deleteL:

```
Foo * p - new Foo();
delete p;
```

And rest of the dynamic memory allocations using new and delete use the default, not yours.
Instead, you may try to overalod global new and delete operator instead of being Foo specific.